# How to pass my variables in a for loop from one function to another

Tags: python, function, for-loop

I want to create an array that collects three variable values.
These variable values are obtained from my Azure Keyvault.

Here is the script:

```
CREDENTIAL = DefaultAzureCredential(exclude_shared_token_cache_credential=True, exclude_environment_credential=True, exclude_managed_identity_credential=True, exclude_visual_studio_code_credential=True)
KV_PARTIAL_NAME = "KeyVault_name-"

def get_secret(kv_client, secret_name):
  return kv_client.get_secret(secret_name).value 

# Subscription identification    
def environments():
  args = parse_arguments() 
  env = args.env_name
  subscription_name = env
  if env == "Prod":
     subscription_name = "Production"
  print(f"The script is running on {subscription_name}")
  azure_key_vault_env_specific_url = f"https://{KV_PARTIAL_NAME}-{env}.vault.azure.net/"
  _secret_client = SecretClient(vault_url=azure_key_vault_env_specific_url, credential=CREDENTIAL)
  configuration = [ ]
  for configuration in _secret_client:
    ELASTIC_SEARCH_USER = _secret_client.get_secret("Elastic--User").value
    ELASTIC_SEARCH_PASSWORD = _secret_client.get_secret("Elastic--Password").value
    ELASTIC_SEARCH_URL = _secret_client.get_secret("Elastic--URL").value
  return azure_key_vault_env_specific_url, configuration

# Provide argument -e for the script to choose the correct subscription
def parse_arguments():
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument('--env_name', '-e', type=str, choices=['Dev', 'QA', 'Prod'],  help='The short for the environment for subscription', required=True)
  return parser.parse_args()

def indice_delete(configuration):
  elastic_auth_uri = f"https://{ELASTIC_SEARCH_URL}/security/_authenticate"
  response = requests.get(elastic_auth_uri, auth=(ELASTIC_SEARCH_USER, ELASTIC_SEARCH_PASSWORD))        
  search_url_index = "_cat/indices/"
  params_dict = {
  "h":"index,docs.count",
  "s":"docs.count:asc",
  "format":"json"
  }
  elastic_console = f"https://{ELASTIC_SEARCH_URL}/{search_url_index}"
  getRequestElasticSearch = requests.get(elastic_console, auth=(ELASTIC_SEARCH_USER, ELASTIC_SEARCH_PASSWORD), params=params_dict)
  content = json.loads(getRequestElasticSearch.text)
  elastic_console_delete = f"https://{ELASTIC_SEARCH_URL}/"
  for index in content:
   indiciesList = index
   collectdoccount = index['docs.count']
   search_int = int(collectdoccount)
   if search_int == 0:
      index_name = index['index']
      delete_url = f"{elastic_console_delete}{index_name}"
      response = requests.delete(delete_url, auth=(ELASTIC_SEARCH_USER, ELASTIC_SEARCH_PASSWORD))
      if  response.status_code == 200:
          print("index deleted -" , "index name:" , index['index'] , ",  doc.count:" , index['docs.count'] , ",  elasticsearch url index:" , delete_url)
      if  response.status_code != 200:
          print ("index not deleted -" , "index name:" , index['index'] , ",  Reason:" , response.content)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   pass_credentials = environments()
   indice_delete(pass_credentials)
```

At the moment, the variables in the for loop (of `environments` function) can't get accessed to other functions e.g. `indice_delete`

Comment: What is the purpose of the `for` loop in the `environments()` function?  It appears to set the same three variables over and over, overwriting them each time through the loop.  Surely that was not your intent?

Comment: There are a number of unrelated issues here, not least of which being indentation. The `for` loop isn't doing what you think it is, as @JohnGordon said. And the `configuration` list in `environments()` isn't being updated anywhere I can see.

Comment: @JRiggles The assignment `configuration = [ ]` on the prior line is immediately discarded anyway, because `configuration` is used as the loop variable...

Comment: All that aside, it's worth pointing out that `indice_delete` is a *function*, which is to say that you can call it from within other functions and pass in any required values...e.g. from inside the aforementioned `for` loop

Comment: @JohnGordon Yep - that too

Comment: The `environments()` function already returns two variables.  If you want it to return more variables, then just add those variables to the `return` statement.  What is the difficulty?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `global` key word to declare the variables as global from inside the function.

```
def environments():
  for configuration in _secret_client:
    global ELASTIC_SEARCH_USER = _secret_client.get_secret("Elastic--User").value
    global ELASTIC_SEARCH_PASSWORD = _secret_client.get_secret("Elastic--Password").value
    global ELASTIC_SEARCH_URL = _secret_client.get_secret("Elastic--URL").value
```

[like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/how-to-use-a-global-variable-in-a-function)

You can also return them, and use the returned values in the next function.

```
return azure_key_vault_env_specific_url, configuration,[ELASTIC_SEARCH_USER,ELASTIC_SEARCH_PASSWORD,ELASTIC_SEARCH_URL]
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by including supporting information in the body of the question. Please demonstrate the implementation of your answer via properly formatted code.

Comment: Why make them global when [it's usually better to avoid global state](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil)? And why would you need to overwrite the values of globals in a loop? Personally, I don't think the question makes enough sense to be able to answer it very well, as explained in the comments.